# Transaction in Enterprise library

Tags: sql-server-2008, enterprise-library

How to handle transaction within a scope using Enterprise library. I've 3 stored procedures, which I need to execute in a single scope. I dont want to use System.Transaction name space

Comment: OK the question has to be asked... *Why* don't you want to use the `System.Transactions` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the BeginTransaction method on a connection object to get a DbTransaction object. Then use the Entlib Database object's overloads that take a DbTransaction. However, it's a giant pain to manage. You'll need to create and close least one connection manually rather than relying on Entlib to do the right thing, and you'll have to pass the DbTransaction object around to everything that needs it.

TransactionScope really is the right answer here. If you've got some blocking scenario that really prevents you from using it that isn't some brain-dead corporate policy, I'd love to know what it is.

Comment: Just thought of an alternative. If it's always those three sprocs in the same order, just create a third sproc that calls them in the right order for you, and then manage the transaction completely inside the database server; the new sproc would do "Begin Trans exec sproc1 exec sproc exec sproc3 Commit Trans" or something like that (my sql's not great).